# How to mock a class in php that is not passed via constructor or method argument ? (phpunit)

Tags: php, phpunit

I am using phpunit and want to write unit tests for a class, which uses another class inside (instantiates object of it).
This other class in not passed via constructor or method argument.
For example in javascript you can mock the module, is something similar in phpunit?

The code is as below:

```
<?php
use SomeLibrary\Resource\Sms;

final class SmsSender
{
    public function __construct(private array $config) {}

    public function send(string $phone, string $content): void
    {
        $sms = new Sms();
        $sms->sendToOne($phone, $content, $this->config['sender']);
    }
}
```

`$sms = new Sms()`

Is there a way to mock globally for my unit test the `Sms` class then stub methods and assert that they are called with the correct arguments

my unit test so far

```
<?php declare(strict_types = 1);

namespace Tests\Unit\App\Services\SmsSender;

use App\Services\SmsSender;
use Tests\Helpers\TestCase;

class SmsSenderTest extends TestCase
{
    private array $config;

    private SmsSender $service;

    public function setUp(): void
    {
        $this->config = [
            'apiKey' => 'mock-api-key',
            'apiSecret' => 'mock-api-secret',
            'sender' => 'my-company-name'
        ];

        $this->service = new SmsSender(
            $this->sms->reveal(),
        );
    }

    public function testSend(): void
    {
        // how to mock the SomeLibrary\Resource\Sms ?
        $this->service->send('+3344334', 'dfddfdfdf');
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

I got two great suggestions from you and posted the implemented solutions from me here, while giving credit to the person that responed.

Comment: One possible approach is to refactor your code to introduce dependency injection. Instead of instantiating the `Sms` object inside the `SmsSender` class, you can pass it as a dependency through the constructor or a setter method.

Comment: Do you use any framework ? you can use Dependency Injection to inject your mock in test environment and your concrete class in other environments

Comment: I am using `phpunit` `"phpunit/phpunit": "^9.3.3",`

Comment: @Kally yes I am aware of that but am not allowed to change it. This particular library will fail to instantiate a `new Sms` if credentials are not set and team does not want to have logic inside the DI container which runs for all the requests. This 3rd party tool is not "test-friendly". Another more complicated solution is to mock the network calls that would work fine but we need to add extra libraries and mix unit with half-integration tests

Comment: _"and team does not want to have logic inside the DI container"_ - Create a factory that handles the instantiation of the SMS service and inject that then? Then you won't have any logic in the container.

Comment: @M.Eriksson yes that is a good idea. I get rid of both concerns 1. not polluting the container.php 2. performance, not running the setCredentials call for every api call but only when the factory creates the smssender (when really needed before the call to send sms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 2 - using factory pattern and di injection**

I also implemented successfully one alternative solution proposed by @m-eriksson
It involves using the `Factory` pattern.
As I did not want to have logic inside the DI container and slow down all calls with runtime code there, I used a factory as second argument of the `SmsSender`
Then mocked the response.

```
final class SmsSender
{
    public function __construct(private array $config, private SmsGlobalSmsFactory $smsFactory)
    {
        Credentials::set($this->config['apiKey'], $this->config['apiSecret']);
    }

    public function send(string $phone, string $content): void
    {
        $sms = $this->smsFactory->create($this->config); // this is the change
        $sms->sendToOne($phone, $content, $this->config['sender']);
    }
}
```

Then in the unit tests had more flexibility

```
    $this->service = new SmsGlobalSmsSender(
            $this->config,
            $this->smsFactory->reveal(),
        );
```

and could mock the response of smsFactory to use a mock and assert all calls and mock the responses.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add an Sms-Stub to your Unit test

```
<?php declare(strict_types = 1);

namespace Tests\Unit\App\Services\SmsSender;

use App\Services\SmsSender;
use Tests\Helpers\TestCase;

class Sms {...
```

As your script runs in namespace Tests\Unit\App\Services\SmsSender, the PHP-Interpreter will first take a look under this Namespace for the Sms-Class

Comment: Thanks for the reply, am not sure I understand. Do you mean to have same namespace as the other library or just re-declare the class in the test class ? I updated my post with the unit-test as well

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question at first. Just try to implement the Sms-Class in your Unit test. I just updated my reply

Comment: Thanks for the update, I understood your answer now and will try it out. So you mean to use old-school manual mock. Then if understood 100% fully I have to keep track of the state and calls and arguments manually in this new Sms class..

Comment: You're welcome. But you should consider using some kind of dependency injection instead which will it make much easier to inject mocks and stubs

Comment: I am already using a DI container but am not allowed to add logic inside it. This particular library will fail to instantiate a new Sms if credentials are not set and team does not want to have logic inside the DI container which runs for all the requests. This 3rd party tool is not "test-friendly". Another more complicated solution is to mock the network calls that would work fine but we need to add extra libraries and mix unit with half-integration tests

Comment: this works fine but other devs don't recommend it adding code that runs on every api call and logic inside the container `<?php
$app->singleton(
    \App\Services\SmsSender\SmsSenderInterface::class,
    function() {
        $config = config('services.smsGlobal');
        \SmsSender\Credentials::set($config['apiKey'], $config['apiSecret']);
        return new \App\Services\SmsSender\SmsSender(
            config('services.smsGlobal'),
            new \SMSGlobal\Resource\Sms()
        );
    }
);`

Comment: The entire trick with this 3rd party is that if you try `new Sms()` it fails unless this call is done beforehand `\SmsSender\Credentials::set($config['apiKey'], $config['apiSecret']);`

Comment: Update: I tried your solution and works fine. Am updating my unit-test in the questions with the solution you proposed, thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1 - using manual mock-stub**

Thanks to @MadCatERZ answer I managed to have my unit test working by re-declaring the Sms class inside the unit test and using a custom mock. It is very hard to stub yourself though, easy to see the calls and arguments only..

my new unit test file looks like

```
<?php declare(strict_types = 1);

namespace Tests\Unit\App\Services\SmsSender;

use App\Services\SmsSender;
use Tests\Helpers\TestCase;

class SmsSenderTest extends TestCase
{
    private array $config;

    private SmsSender $service;

    public function setUp(): void
    {
        $this->config = [
            'apiKey' => 'mock-api-key',
            'apiSecret' => 'mock-api-secret',
            'sender' => 'my-company-name'
        ];

        $this->service = new SmsSender(
            $this->sms->reveal(),
        );
    }

    public function testSend(): void
    {
        $phoneNumber = '+3344334';
        $content = 'dfddfdfdf';
        $this->service->send($phoneNumber, $content);
        self::assertEquals([$phoneNumber, $content, $this->config['sender']], Sms::$calls['sendToOne'][0]);
    }
}

namespace SomeLibrary\Resource\Sms;
class Sms {
    public static array $calls = [];

    public function sendToOne(string $phone, string $content, string $sender): void {
        if (!array_key_exists('sendToOne', self::$calls)) {
            self::$calls['sendToOne'] = [];
        }
        self::$calls['sendToOne'][] = func_get_args();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are already testing `Sms::sendToOne()` method there is no need to test `SmsSender::send()` as well. In your case `send()` is just a wrapper over `sendToOne()` and doesn't do any extra logic.

If you were to add more code in `SmsSender::send()` then I am sad to say you cannot mock the `Sms` class.